# What is the correct implementation of the Open Graph "article" type?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, article

I need to add Open Graph tags to a blog page. It seems from reading the spec (http://ogp.me/) using an `og:type` of `article` is the way to go. However, I find the spec unclear and I'm unsure how to implement the syntax correctly.

Two example websites implement this differently for example:

1. Example from GitHub: (https://github.com/niallkennedy/open-graph-protocol-examples/blob/master/article-utc.html)

   ```html
   <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
   <meta property="og:title" content="...">
   <meta property="og:type" content="article">
   <meta property="article:published_time" content="...">
   ```

   *Note the `og` and `article` namespaces are registered and that `og` and `article` are used as properties.*
2. BBC News article

   ```html
   <head>
   <meta property="og:title" content="...">
   <meta property="og:type" content="article">
   <meta property="og:article:author" content="...">
   ```

   *Note no namespace registration and `og` and `og:article` are used as properties.*
3. A variation I've seen in the wild of the above, registering only the `og` namespace and still referencing `og:article` as a property.

   ```html
   <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
   <meta property="og:title" content="...">
   <meta property="og:type" content="article">
   <meta property="og:article:published_time" content="..">
   ```

Option 3 is what I used the first time I tried to implement this. When I ran it through the Facebook validation tool I was told:

> Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:article:published_time'.

For the moment, I have gone with option 1 and although this validates, I would like to know what the definitive correct syntax is?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have a look at the Facebook developers page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article

It looks like your examples 2 and 3 have incorrect formatting. None of the "article" properties should begin with "og:"

Here's what I have on one of my sites, and I get no errors from the FB debugger:

```
<meta property='og:type' content='article' />
<meta property='article:author' content='https://www.facebook.com/YOUR-NAME' />
<meta property='article:publisher' content='https://www.facebook.com/YOUR-PAGE' />
<meta property='og:site_name' content='YOUR-SITE-NAME' />
```

Comment: is `article:author` must be url? coz my author doesn't have fb.

Comment: @Elyor Yes it must be a URL. If you try to put just a name like e.g. "Mary Smith" Facebook Debugger will show you an error. But the URL does not necessarily have to point to a Facebook account. For example one can put a link to her about.me profile "https://about.me/marysmith".

Comment: **additionally you could add:** article:expiration_time DateTime
article:modified_time DateTime
article:published_time DateTime, cheers

Comment: As of Oct 2021, the Facebook link is broken.

Comment: Here is a thorough description of the OG types https://ogp.me/#types

Answer (score 11):

You can use this killer Open Graph Article Generator tool to generate your code for you and to help answer any questions you have about formatting/protocol.

[Open Graph Generator | Article](https://webcode.tools/open-graph-generator/article)

There's also a very helpful tip for the `author` property that says...

> Provide a URL to the author's Facebook profile or a page with open graph data of type profile.

So you don't have to use a Facebook profile necessarily as long as there are Open Graph Profile tags on the page you link to. And if you're confused about the Open Graph Profile tags there's a Profile Generator too...

[Open Graph Generator | Profile](https://webcode.tools/open-graph-generator/profile)

Answer (score -4):

```
you can  post this code to your blog or article header


<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/author/"/>
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-11-26T17:41:45+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-11-27T00:32:23+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2017-11-27T00:32:23+00:00" />
```

Answer (score -7):

This is an example from http://ogp.me/#array

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
```

Comment: OP asked for tag `article`, not for image.